# No puedo abrir las imágenes en jupyter

Tags: python

Resulta que para una práctica de la Universidad necesito trabajar con unas imágenes que nos proporciona el profesor en una carpeta,el problema es que al guardar esta carpeta en la de python y luego llamar a esa imágen en jupyter según nos dice el rpofesor me salta que no envuentra esa imágen, no se si es por estar en formato png o por qué, por favor ayúdenme,muchas gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la ruta completa ya que probablemente el script se ejecuta en una ruta distinta, esto lo puedes averiguar ejecutando lo siguiente

```py
import os
print os.path.realpath('.')
```

Esto te devolverá la ruta de ejecución de tu script y ya con eso podrás jugar y concatenar bien la ruta para abrir tu imagen.